# Embed API suitable for public viewing?

Tags: google-analytics

Is the Embed API suitable for me to create some read-only charts to put on my web site for public viewing? The charts should pull data from GA in real time when the page is loaded. There has to be no authorization required.

I am not referring to using the API as a property owner to review my own statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can follow this guidelines: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started